# what is the difference between grails filters and hibernate grails filter plug-ins

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

Grails filter plug-in    `compile "org.grails.plugins:filter:0.2"`

Grails Hibernate filter plug-in `compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate-filter:0.3.2"`

I wanted to know, when exactly we are going to use these 2 plug-ins and main difference between these 2 plug-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two entirely different types of plugins.

The `hibernate-filter` plugin is used to create filters on domain classes and associations that can be enabled/disabled within your code.

The `filters` plugin is a UI plugin for filtering data in collections.